# Visual Studio auto restores dll packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, dll-dependency

In the company I work, inside every solution we have one folder *packages*, which contains all dll dependencies. This folder is not in repository with the rest of the solution.

Every time I build one project, all files inside folder *packages* are restored and any missing dlls appear again. This happens in the beginning of the build, no matter if the build succeeds of fails. Even if the project has no dll dependencies, any missing dlls in *packages* are restored.

I suspect it is a setting in msbuild but I cannot find it. Does anyone know where it might be or if there is a place with msbuild *.targets files?

thanks for any help

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is because Visual Studio restores packages defined in the `packages.config` files.

You can control this behaviour in Visual Studio in options:
[image: VS NuGet options]

Comment: I knew these settings in NuGet, but I would like to understand the mechanism, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

From the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore) regarding regarding Nuget:

> MSBuild: use the msbuild -t:restore command, which restores packages
>   packages listed in the project file (PackageReference only). Available
>   only in NuGet 4.x+ and MSBuild 15.1+, which are included with Visual
>   Studio 2017. nuget restore and dotnet restore both use this command
>   for applicable projects.

Further down, there's quite a bit about enabling/disabling and modifying this behavior in a variety of ways.

> Allow NuGet to download missing packages: controls all forms of
>   package restore by changing the packageRestore/enabled setting in the
>   NuGet.Config file as shown below (%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.Config on
>   Windows, ~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config on Mac/Linux). In Visual Studio,
>   this setting allows the Restore NuGet Packages command on the
>   solution's context menu to work.

Appearing to be more to your issue:

> Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual
>   Studio: controls automatic restore by changing the
>   packageRestore/automatic setting in the NuGet.Config file as shown
>   below (%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.Config on Windows,
>   ~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config on Mac/Linux). When this option is set,
>   running a build from Visual Studio automatically restores any missing
>   packages. The option does not affect builds run from the command line
>   using MSBuild.

Comment: thanks for your help, this information is really valuable

Comment: My pleasure! There's so much about VS that just happens automagically but MS seems to be trying to beef up the docs lately to shed some more light.